# Is it appropriate to hardcode expected results when unit testing date and time formatting?

Tags: unit-testing

I like to keep my unit tests pretty simple and easy to follow.  I often hardcode the expected results of a test in order to avoid repeating the code that I am testing.  In addition, I often use data-driven tests.  For example, if I am testing the format that a date/time is presented as, I will sometimes hard-code the expected string, ie. "1/1/2000" or "1:00 PM".  However, since date and time formats are culture-specific and our app is localizable, the actual output COULD vary.  However, my team is based in the U.S. and so this is usually not a problem.  Our continuous integration and build servers run with U.S. culture info as well.

There is a team member who has complained because he has changed the date format on his dev machine to manually test other date formats, and so many tests fail for him.  Should I be using the current culture information when testing outputs in unit tests, or is this hard-coding acceptable?

UPDATE: I ended up setting a specific locale for certain tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unit tests should be 100% repeatable, regardless of the environment in which they run. The only reason for a unit test to start failing is because the code changed and broke the test.

So yes, you need to take steps to ensure that your tests continue to pass regardless of external factors.

Comment: +1 for repeatable tests. Not so sure about "you should be using the current culture information." Consider setting expected culture for tests tat are not concerned about input/output and have separate tests that go over multiple cultures to validate parsing/formatting for different cultures.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Fair enough. I made my response a bit more general :)

Answer (score 3):

It is, of course, okay to hard-code the result, but you'll need to provide a test-double for the locale information to ensure that the unit test is isolated from the environment.

You could even add a new unit test with a test-double emulating the other developer's locale settings.

Your unit tests should run and pass on any machine.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should have a separate suite of tests that pins down your localization. As far as testing for the current culture goes, my first choice would be to force your specific locale onto the test execution environment, rather than relying on the default provided by the operating system. If this is not possible, I would parameterize my unit tests by the current locale, in a way similar to how you handle localization in the main system, and read the expected values from that localizable storage. The important point is that switching the settings on the host computer should not be enough to bring down your unit test suite.